# How to filter out duplicates and increment in a Google table-chart

Tags: javascript, django, object, google-visualization

I want to loop through a list of objects and store that result in a Google-chart table. But before I draw the table, I want to go through the list and see if there are any duplicates. If there are any duplicate I want to remove the it, but want to increment the one that isn't removed.

```
function drawTable()
    {
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string', 'Teamname');
    data.addColumn('number', 'Number of resources');
    var number = 1;
    {% for k, v in teammember %}
        {% for object in object_list %}
            data.addRows([['{{ object.team.name }}', number]]);
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}


    var table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table-div'));

    table.draw(data, {showRowNumber: true, width: '100%', height: '100%'});
    }
```

As you can see here I have one column for the name of a team and one should contain the number of members associated to that team.

So in my for-loop I find all the teams, but how should I build the rest of the code for finding the duplicates, increment, and remove the duplicate. 
So a example could look like:

- Name - Team-members
- Junior Bobcat     3
- Team Bobcat       4
- Junior Coffe      4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

recommend using google's [group()](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#google_visualization_data_group) method

> Takes a populated DataTable object and performs a SQL-like GROUP BY operation, returning a table with rows grouped by the specified column values.

go ahead and load your data table without finding duplicates or incrementing

then use the the `group` method and use the grouped table to draw the chart

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  packages: ['table']
}).then(function () {
  var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
  data.addColumn('string', 'Teamname');
  data.addColumn('number', 'Number of resources');

  data.addRow(['Junior Bobcat', 1]);
  data.addRow(['Team Bobcat', 1]);
  data.addRow(['Junior Coffe', 1]);
  data.addRow(['Junior Bobcat', 1]);
  data.addRow(['Team Bobcat', 1]);
  data.addRow(['Junior Coffe', 1]);
  data.addRow(['Junior Bobcat', 1]);
  data.addRow(['Team Bobcat', 1]);
  data.addRow(['Junior Coffe', 1]);
  data.addRow(['Team Bobcat', 1]);
  data.addRow(['Junior Coffe', 1]);


  var dataGroup = google.visualization.data.group(
    data,
    [0],
    [{
      column: 1,
      type: 'number',
      label: data.getColumnLabel(1),
      aggregation: google.visualization.data.sum
    }]
  );

  var table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table-div'));
  table.draw(dataGroup, {showRowNumber: true, width: '100%', height: '100%'});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="table-div"></div>
```